# Sort a data.table programmatically using character vector of multiple column names

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I need to sort a `data.table` on multiple columns provided as character vector of variable names.

This is my approach so far:

```
DT = data.table(x = rep(c("b","a","c"), each = 3), y = c(1,3,6), v = 1:9)

#column names to sort by, stored in a vector
keycol <- c("x", "y")

DT[order(keycol)]
   x y v
1: b 1 1
2: b 3 2
```

Somehow It displays just 2 rows and removes other records. But if I do this:

```
DT[order(x, y)]
   x y v
1: a 1 4
2: a 3 5
3: a 6 6
4: b 1 1
5: b 3 2
6: b 6 3
7: c 1 7
8: c 3 8
9: c 6 9
```

It works like fluid.
Can anyone help with sorting using column name vector?

Comment: `order(keycol)` returns `1:2`. With a single argument, `data.table` subsets on the rows. This behavior is different from a data.frame, which subsets on columns. You're telling `data.table` to keep rows 1 and 2.

Comment: `setkeyv(DT, c('x', 'y'))` if you want to key and order

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need `?setorderv` and its `cols` argument:

> A character vector of column names of `x` by which to order

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
#column vector
keycol <-c("x","y")
setorderv(DT, keycol)
DT
   x y v
1: a 1 4
2: a 3 5
3: a 6 6
4: b 1 1
5: b 3 2
6: b 6 3
7: c 1 7
8: c 3 8
9: c 6 9
```

Note that there is no need to assign the output of `setorderv` back to `DT`. The function updates `DT` by reference.

Comment: `setorderv` has an `order` argument which you can set to -1 to sort descending.