# Easily Switch Which Columns Ordered By

Tags: r, sorting, arguments

R uses the three dot ellipses (`...`) in the function `order(...)` to pass the multiple vectors to order by. The function immediately converts the `...` to a list with `z <- list(...)`.

Let's say we have:

```r
dat = data.frame(A = c(rep("b", 2), rep("a", 2)),
                 B = letters[1:4],
                 C = letters[4:1])
```

I would like to be able to easily change which columns I want to use (the variable `cols`) so I don't need to hard code them, incase I want different ones or their names change. Which would look something like this:

```r
cols = c("A", "B")
dat[order(dat[,cols]), ]
```

But doing the above is equivalent to doing:

```r
dat[order(c(dat$A, dat$B)), ]
```

Which obviously doesn't work, because it combines the columns into a single vector, so the list created by `order()` only has the one element, not two.

Is there a way to dynamically create the `...` that is passed to functions? Or some other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Related `data.table` alternative using `setorderv`: [Sort a data.table programmatically using character vector of multiple column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282341/sort-a-data-table-programmatically-using-character-vector-of-multiple-column-nam)